# XSL: get the position of a node that matches

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to rewrite the following without for-each:

```
<xsl:for-each select="$nodeTree">
   <xsl:if test="@value = $myVariable"> 
      <xsl:value-of select="position()" /></xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

The above iterates through every item in the tree, and if it matches it prints the position. It works.

How can I rewrite that in one line using a predicate instead of a for-each?

My attempt at this was:

```
<xsl:value-of select="$nodeTree[@value = $myVariable][position()]" />
```

... but that doesn't work. Is it really necessary to use a for-each?

Many thanks!
P.S. I'm using XSLT 1.0.

Comment: You can certainly shorten the `<xsl:for-each select="$nodeTree"><xsl:if test="@value = $myVariable"> ` to `<xsl:for-each select="$nodeTree[@value = $myVariable]">`.

Comment: That appears to have taken out the scope of the position() ... now it always return 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I rewrite that in one line using a predicate instead of a
>   for-each?

I would be much more comfortable answering this if you had shown us an input example to test against, instead of leaving us guessing.

In any case, I suppose you could use:

```
<xsl:value-of select="count($nodeTree[@value=$myVariable]/preceding-sibling::*) + 1" />
```

provided you can be confident that a node matching your variable does exist (otherwise you will get a false answer of 1).

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`xsl:number`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#number) instead of `position()`.

Since you're using XSLT 1.0, you may still have to use the `xsl:for-each`...

```
<xsl:for-each select="$nodeTree[@value=$myVariable]">
    <xsl:number/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

If you were using XSLT 2.0, you could use the [`select` attribute on `xsl:number`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#number)...

```
<xsl:number select="$nodeTree[@value=$myVariable]"/>
```